# Nancy register dependency with type argument

Tags: dependency-injection, nancy

Nancy auto-registration of dependencies is having trouble resolving a dependency with a type argument, so I'm trying to manually register it and cannot figure it out.

```
public abstract class BaseE { }
public abstract class BaseS<T> where T : BaseE { }
public class E : BaseE { }
public interface ISomething { }
public class S<T> : BaseS<T> where T : BaseE, ISomething { }
```

I want ISomething to be auto-resolved to class S, but that's not working, so I created a custom bootstrapper:

```
public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
        protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
        {
            base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
            // Works fine, but not sure if necessary
            container.Register<E, BaseE>();
            // Cannot get the syntax right, doesn't compile
            // ??? container.Register<ISomething, S<E>>();
        }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the syntax. The line `container.Register<ISomething, S<E>>();` gives me a compile error: `The type S<E> cannot be used as type parameter 'RegisterImplementation' in the generic type or method 'TinyIoCContainer.Register<RegisterType, RegisterImplementation()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'S<E>' to 'ISomething'`

Please help me figure out what the correct syntax / correct way to register a dependency with a type argument.

Comment: The problem is that `S<T>` doesn't implement `ISomething` (`T` implements `ISomething`).

Comment: Really? That would make sense but then what is the correct syntax for class S? I want to say that T extends BaseE, and that class S<T> implements ISomething, I thought that was what `class S<T> : BaseS<T> where T : BaseE, ISomething {}` did. How do I tell the compiler that S implements ISomething, not generic type T?

Comment: ahhhh figured it out based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007429/inherit-from-a-generic-base-class-apply-a-constraint-and-implement-an-interfac), you were right, my syntax was wrong, should be `public class S<T> : BaseS<T>, ISomething where T : BaseE { }`

Comment: The problem isn't related to Nancy at all, the problem was with the C# syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to incorrect syntax as pointed out by qujck.

```
public class S<T> : BaseS<T> where T : BaseE, ISomething { }
```

should be

```
public class S<T> : BaseS<T>, ISomething where T : BaseE { }
```

The first syntax says that type T extends BaseE **AND** implements ISomething, the second syntax says that type T only extends BaseE (and S implements ISomething). Dependency auto-injection is now working as expected.

Comment: does this mean you can leave out your custom bootstrapper or is it still necessary?

Comment: I found that the custom bootstrapper isn't necessary most of the time, but after I run my tests then go to run the application Nancy is unable to find the dependencies. I uncomment the custom bootstrapper and everything works, then I comment it back out and auto-dependency injection works again, but if I run my tests then it will sometimes fail so I just kept the custom bootstrapper code but left it commented out.